# import play.Project in Play 2.3 not working

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

In an older Play app (v 2.2.x) I have the following in my Build.scala

```
import play.Project._
```

In v.2.3 this is not compiling

Is there any reason for this based on the version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the migration guide

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23 - scroll down to `Build Changes`

Near: "If you were previously using play.Project, for example a Scala project [...] then you can continue to use a similar approach via native sbt"

Answer (score 2):

Need to take care while migrating - in Build.scala

In Play 2.2

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import PlayProject._
```

Migrate to Play 2.3, add the followings

```
import play.Play.autoImport._
import PlayKeys._
```

Remove `import PlayProject._`

Add also

**If Java Project**

`val main = Project(appName, file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayJava).settings(
    version := appVersion,
    libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies
  )`

**If Scala Project**

`val main = Project(appName, file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala).settings(
    version := appVersion,
    libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies
  )`

Instead of

`val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings()`

Don't need to add the `scalaVersion := "2.11.1"` in `Build.scala` or `build.sbt` file as suggested in the **Play 2.3** Migration Guide. In **Play 2.2** the `Build.scala` or `build.sbt` file structure is different.

Comment: can you please take a look at this post