# play framework java - Build.scala - not found: value cache

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I am currently trying to use the [Cache](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.0/JavaCache) api in my application and am having trouble importing the dependency.

Here is my build.scala (using this for now as opposed to build.sbt):

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
//import play.PlayProject._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "resthandshake"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val main = Project(appName, file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayJava).settings(
    version := appVersion,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      // Add your project dependencies here,
      cache
    ))
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Documents\testprojects\resthandshake\project\Build.scala:23: not found: value cache
[error]       cache
[error]       ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

**Additional details include...**

My plugins.sbt:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.0")
```

My build.properties includes just the line: sbt.version=0.13.5

Finally the way I'm importing and using the Cache api (Note that these lines are currently throwing error as the import and Cache are not recognized):

```
import play.cache.Cache;
...
Cache.set("cars", cars, 0);
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so turns out I found a fix for this, even after struggling for days, a little bit after posting my question (stack overflow = good luck charm?)

So i had confused the setup for build.scala between play 2.2 and play 2.3. 
the way i have it up there is for play 2.2, to migrate properly to play 2.3 i just did the following according to royki's answer to this question [import play.Project in Play 2.3 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259240/import-play-project-in-play-2-3-not-working)

1. add the following imports:

   import play.Play.autoImport._

   import PlayKeys._
2. Remove import PlayProject._
3. ensure i am using play 2.3.0 in plugins.sbt